# Why data[0] isn't showing error when Map is of type <String, String>

Tags: dart

```
Map<String, String> data = {
  "string" : "string",
};

String item = data[0]; // why data[0] isn't showing any error
```

Shouldn't `data`'s `[]` accept a `String` as declared by the types `<String, String>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the Dart `Map<K, V>`'s [index operator](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Map/operator_get.html) is `V operator[](Object key)`.

It is so because Dart has covariant generics, so a `Map<String, String>` is-a `Map<Object, Object>`, and a number of methods on `Map` (and other collections) take `Object` as argument so that you can do `Map<Object, Object> objectMap = stringMap; objectMap[anyObject];`.
(Other examples are [`Iterable.contains`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html) or [`List.remove`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/List/remove.html)).

Dart is not the only language doing this. Java does [the same thing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) for the same reasons.